# Controlling volume of running applications in Mac OS X via Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-audio

Please edvice by objective-c code snippets and useful links of how can I control all audio signals of output in OS X?

I think it should be something like proxy layer somewhere in OS X logic layers.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 4):

It's somewhat sad that there is no simple API to do this.  Luckily it isn't too hard, just verbose.

First, get the system output device:

```
UInt32 size;
AudioDeviceID outputDevice;
OSStatus result = AudioHardwareGetProperty(kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOuputDevice, &size, &outputDevice);
```

Then set the volume:

```
Float32 theVolume;
result = AudioDeviceSetProperty(theDevice, NULL, 0, /* master channel */ false, kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar, sizeof(Float32), &theVolume);
```

Obviously I've omitted any error checking, which is a must.

Things can get a bit tricky because not all devices support channel 0 (the master channel).  If this is the case with your device (it probably is) you have two options: query the device for its preferred stereo pair and set the volume on those channels individually, or just set the volume on channels 1 and 2.

Comment: Hi sbooth, thank you very much! Thats a basic idea of getting mixer, i got it, but what about adjusting volume output of each **application**? Thank you!

Comment: That depends on how you are playing the sounds.  Are you using NSSound, AUGraph, or something else?

Comment: dear sbooth, I'm not playing sound, I just want to change the volume of sound (which sources are other apps). So I do not want to play sound, I want to know how to modify level volume of them. In best case I'd like to know how to control them, like DSP and VST but during run-time and over system sounds. Thank you very much! Appreciate your help very very much!

Comment: In that case, I don't think you'll be able to do this unless the specific applications that happen to be running support volume control through either AppleScript or some other API.  OS X doesn't let you do this.

Comment: Please note that `AudioHardwareGetProperty` is deprecated since 10.6. :-(