# Controlling OS X volume in Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, core-audio

This is a follow up to [Controlling volume of running applications in Mac OS X via Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109971/controlling-volume-of-running-applications-in-mac-os-x-via-objective-c), which explains how to set the volume for 10.5 or earlier. The `AudioXXXXXGetProperty`, and `AudioXXXXXSetProperty` (and related) functions are deprecated in 10.6, per [Technical Note TN2223](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2010/tn2223.html).

I'm not an expert in OS X or CoreAudio programming, so I'm hoping someone has muddled through what's required in Snow Leopard and can help me (and others) out here.

Comment: @drcosta - Figuring it out on your own is always a plus but please post it as an answer (and accept it) to your question rather than an edit.  That way someone looking for a similar solution won't skip over this page after noticing there are no accepted answers.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize SO let you accept your own answers now. (At least, I remember thinking at some point in the past that you couldn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example to set volume to 50%:

```
Float32 volume = 0.5;
UInt32 size = sizeof(Float32);

AudioObjectPropertyAddress address = {
    kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar,
    kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
    1 // use values 1 and 2 here, 0 (master) does not seem to work
};

OSStatus err;
err = AudioObjectSetPropertyData(device, &address, 0, NULL, size, &volume);
```