# Change OS X system volume programmatically

Tags: objective-c, osx-mountain-lion, core-audio

How can I change the volume programmatically from Objective-C?

I found this question, *[Controlling OS X volume in Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286092/controlling-os-x-volume-in-snow-leopard)* which suggests to do:

```
Float32 volume = 0.5;
UInt32 size = sizeof(Float32);

AudioObjectPropertyAddress address = {
    kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar,
    kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
    1 // Use values 1 and 2 here, 0 (master) does not seem to work
};

OSStatus err;
err = AudioObjectSetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &address, 0, NULL, size, &volume);
NSLog(@"status is %i", err);
```

This does nothing for me, and prints out `status is 2003332927`.

I also tried using values `2` and `0` in the `address` structure, same result for both.

How can I fix this and make it actually decrease the volume to 50%?

Comment: You can do it easily with AppleScript.

Comment: @TBlue: yes, I know, but I'd rather do it directly in Objective-C.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to get the default audio device first:

```
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h>

AudioObjectPropertyAddress getDefaultOutputDevicePropertyAddress = {
  kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice,
  kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
  kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
};

AudioDeviceID defaultOutputDeviceID;
UInt32 volumedataSize = sizeof(defaultOutputDeviceID);
OSStatus result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject,
                                             &getDefaultOutputDevicePropertyAddress,
                                             0, NULL,
                                             &volumedataSize, &defaultOutputDeviceID);

if(kAudioHardwareNoError != result)
{
  // ... handle error ...
}
```

You can then set your volume on channel 1 (left) and channel 2 (right). Note that channel 0 (master) does not seem to be supported (the set command returns 'who?')

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress volumePropertyAddress = {
  kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar,
  kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
  1 /*LEFT_CHANNEL*/
};

Float32 volume;
volumedataSize = sizeof(volume);

result = AudioObjectSetPropertyData(defaultOutputDeviceID,
                                    &volumePropertyAddress,
                                    0, NULL,
                                    sizeof(volume), &volume);
if (result != kAudioHardwareNoError) {
  // ... handle error ...
}
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thank you for the tips.  I wanted to suppress the default system sound (e.g., "funk") when hitting a function key.  My solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62078055/236415) needed to get and set the volume level.  Plus 1.

Comment: > You can then set your volume on channel 1 (left) and channel 2 (right). Note that channel 0 (master) does not seem to be supported (the set command returns 'who?').  
                     .
It seems that now only channel 0 is supported and channels 1 and 2 can not be used anymore (at least on my M1 mac with macOS 12.5.1)

Comment: 'who?' refers to `kAudioHardwareUnknownPropertyError`, which indicate the default output device does not support this channel(primary or channel).

Answer (score 1):

I ran the HALLab utility that comes with the developer tools (i.e. Audio Tools for Xcode).  That allows you to open an info window for individual devices and that window has a tab showing notifications.  When I change my system volume, I do indeed see that the `kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar` property changes for each channel of the output device as Thomas O'Dell's answer suggests.  However, I also see the property `kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume` change on the master channel.  That seems much more promising since you don't have to manually set it for all channels and maintain the balance across them.

You would use the function `AudioHardwareServiceSetPropertyData()` from [Audio Hardware Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioHardwareServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) to set that on the default output device.  To be safe, you might first check that it's settable using `AudioHardwareServiceIsPropertySettable()`.

The documentation for that property says:

> `kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume`
>
> A `Float32` value that represents the value of the volume control.
>
> The range for this property’s value is 0.0 (silence) through 1.0 (full level). The effect of this property depends on the hardware device associated with the HAL audio object. If the device has a master volume control, this property controls it. If the device has individual channel volume controls, this property applies to those identified by the device's preferred multichannel layout, or the preferred stereo pair if the device is stereo only. This control maintains relative balance between the channels it affects.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a bash script that will change the master volume. This prevents setting the audio first to one side:

Muted:

```
execlp("osascript", "osascript", "-e", "set volume output muted true", NULL);
```

Change volume (scale 0-10):

```
    execlp("osascript", "osascript", "-e", "set volume 5", NULL);
```

Comment: On my system this seems to be out of 7, not 10. To get it to match the 16 segments in the system's volume key overlay, you can use something like ((7 / 16) * x) to get a float value and supply that.